# Python I/O: Mixing The Datatypes

Tags: python, json, file-io, types

I'm writing a small script which merges a host of JSON files in one directory into a single file. Trouble is, I'm not entirely sure when my data is in which state. TypeErrors abound. Here's the script;

```
import glob
import json
import codecs

reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")

for file in glob.glob("/Users/me/Scripts/BagOfJson/*.json"):
#Aha, as binary here
with open(file, "rb") as infile:
    data = json.load(reader(infile))
    #If I print(data) here, looks like good ol' JSON

    with open("test.json", "wb") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)
    #Crash
```

This script results in the following error;

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Which is caused by the json.dump line.

Naive me just deletes the 'b' in 'wb' for the outfile open. That doesn't do the trick.

Maybe this is a lesson to me to use the shell for testing, and making use of the type() python function. Still, I'd love if someone can clear up for me the logic behind these data swaps. I wish it could all be strings...

Comment: What happened when you removed the `'b'`? Did you get a *different* error perhaps?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, Martijn, I'll tell you what happens when I remove the 'b' in 'wb.' It works. I must have had another error at the time that I tried that. Thank you for the wise question! This is python 3

Comment: Yes, in Python 3, `json.dump()` always writes *Unicode strings*, so you want to write this to a text file (so no `'b'`).

Comment: Thank you :) Glad to have your expertise here

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python 3, removing the `b` (binary mode) to open the file in *text mode* should work just fine. You probably want to specify the encoding explicitly:

```
with open("test.json", "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)
```

rather than rely on a default.

You shouldn't really use `codecs.getreader()`. The standard `open()` function can handle UTF-8 files just fine; just open the file in text mode and specify the encoding again:

```
import glob
import json

for file in glob.glob("/Users/me/Scripts/BagOfJson/*.json"):
    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf8') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        with open("test.json", "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False)
```

The above will still re-create `test.json` for each file in the `*.json` glob; you can't really put multiple JSON documents in the same file anyway (unless you specifically create [JSONLines files](http://jsonlines.org/), which you are not doing here because you are using `indent`).

You'd need to write to a new filename and move the new back to the `file` filename if you wanted to re-format all JSON files in the glob.